# Tomcat Server Not Starting - Tried Changing Connection port as well

Tags: tomcat, server

I am a beginner in working with Apache Tomcat server. I got stuck with this error please help me to get out of this issue.

```
05-Oct-2019 17:06:41.121 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
05-Oct-2019 17:07:23.154 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8088]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1059)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:304)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:52)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.close(NioSelectorPool.java:119)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1129)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1137)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:574)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source)
                ... 30 more
05-Oct-2019 17:07:23.164 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8008"]
05-Oct-2019 17:08:05.196 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8008]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1059)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:304)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:52)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.close(NioSelectorPool.java:119)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1129)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1137)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:574)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source)
                ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved : I came to know that my antivirus firewall was blocking the tomcat server to get started on the specified port address so i simply disabled my antivirus firewall start tomcat server. Now its working fine.